# The right way to navigate between items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I do a little project in react
now I have a list of movies and for eace movie has a movie page that display a details on the movie  I want to click on each of them and navigate to movie page by pass the id of the movie I click and get it with axios from TMDB API
so whet is The right way to do that?

this is the way I tried but there is a few problems

```js
 const displayMovie = () => {
        const el = props.item //item is the card of each movie
        navigate(`/${el.title || el.name}`, { push: true, state: { titleid: el.id } });

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import axios from "axios"
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom"
import CardItem from "../../CardItem/CardItem"


function MoviePage(props) {

    const [moviePage, setMoviePage] = useState([])
    // console.log(location)
    const location = useLocation();
    console.log(location.state.titleid)


    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${location.state.titleid}?api_key=0a298b024e6a7a2e4b6724e36952cf68&language=en-US`)
            .then(item => {
                let set = []
                // console.log(item.data)
                set.push(item.data)
                setMoviePage(set)

                console.log(set)
            })

    }, [])
    console.log(moviePage)
    console.log(moviePage.id)


    return (
        <div>
            {moviePage.map(item => {
                console.log(item)
                return <div key={item.id}>
                    <img name='img' className="img-card" src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${item.poster_path}`} />
                    <p> {item.original_title || item.name}</p>
                    <p> {item.overview}</p>
                    <p> {item.runtime}m</p>
                </div>

            })}
        </div>
    )

}

export default MoviePage
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import './CardItem.css'
import { addDoc, doc, deleteDoc, Firestore, query, where, Store } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db, colRef, docRef } from '../../firebase-config'
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "../Home/Home";


const CardItemFunc = (props) => {

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    let el = props.item
    const send = props.send
    // console.log(el)

    const [booked, setBooked] = useState(false)
    const [title, settitle] = useState(null)

    const bookmark = (props) => {
        // const el = props.item
        send(el)
        setBooked(true)
    }

    const deleteBookMark = (e) => {
        // const el = this.props.item
        // colRef.where("moviedId", '==', el.id).get().then((snapshot) => {
        //     snapshot.docs.first.reference.delete();
        //     console.log(snapshot)
        // });
        // const el = props.item
        const docRef = doc(db, 'bookmarks', `${el.id}`)
        // console.log(docRef)
        deleteDoc(docRef)
    }

    const displayMovie = () => {
        console.log(el.id)
        console.log(el.title)
        console.log('clck')
        navigate(`/${el.title || el.name}`, { push: true, state: { titleid: el.id } });

    }


    return (
        <div className="container-card">
            <img onClick={(e) => displayMovie(e)} name='img' className="img-card" src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${props.item.backdrop_path}`} />
            <p name='title' data-text={props.item.title} className="title">{props.item.title || props.item.name}</p>
            <p name='type' className="titletype"> {props.item.media_type}</p>
            <p name='year'>  {props.item.release_date || props.item.first_air_date}</p>
            <button onClick={(e) => bookmark(e)} className={booked ? "bookmarked" : "icon"} name='icon' ><ion-icon name="bookmark-outline"></ion-icon></button>
            <button onClick={(e) => deleteBookMark(e)} className="icondelete" name='icon' ><ion-icon name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon></button>
        </div>

    )
}

export default CardItemFunc
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
// import CardItem from '../CardItem/CardItem';
import NavBar from '../NavBar/NavBar';
import Logo from '../Logo/Logo';
import './Home.css'
import { addDoc, getDocs, doc, deleteDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db, colRef, auth, colRef1, docRef } from '../../firebase-config'
import CardItemFunc from '../CardItem/CardItemFunction';

class Home extends Component {
    state = {
        listItem: []
    }


    componentDidMount() {


        axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=0a298b024e6a7a2e4b6724e36952cf68')
            .then(item => {
                // console.log(item.data.results)
                let listMovies = []
                item.data.results.forEach(item => {
                    listMovies.push(item)
                })
                this.setState({ listItem: listMovies })
            })
    }



    bookmark = (el) => {
        addDoc(colRef, {
            userID: auth.currentUser.email,
            movieId: el.id
        })
    }





    render() {
        return (
            <div className='dad1' >
                <NavBar />
                <Logo />

                <div className='dad'>
                    {
                        this.state.listItem.map(item => {
                            return <CardItemFunc send={this.bookmark} item={item} key={item.id} id={item.id} />
                        })
                    }
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what are those problems ?

Comment: 1. I manage to show only one movie from the whole list, the others don't work                    I get this error: No routes matched location "/Goodnight%20Mommy"  
Routes@http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:86157:7
div
App
Router@http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:86094:7
BrowserRouter@http://localhost:3002/static/js/bundle.js:84900:7
                                                                                                                2. If I'm in the movie page and I marker the URL and press enter, it gives me an error:
Uncaught TypeError: location.state is null

Comment: It's really hard to help you with minimal code attached which is not related to the issues mentioned, please try to attach some code or a working sample to reproduce it (you can use codesandbox / stackblitz) and share the link

Comment: I added the related code